# How can i make this code for creating a truth table simpler?

Tags: java

This code is for creating the truth table of a or (b and c) given to me as a classwork, and I was wondering is this a good code, can it be improve or more simpler than this.

In case my teacher sees this and think I copy from this,
this is the course id, and my id: "CE4715", 6135113.

```
package truth_table;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.*;

public class Truth_tb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false;
        boolean[] a = {f,f,f,f,t,t,t,t};
        boolean[] b = {f,f,t,t,f,f,t,t};
        boolean[] c = {f,t,f,t,f,t,f,t};
        
        boolean[] bac = null;
        boolean[] aobac = null;
        //For b and c
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            if (b[i] != c[i]) {
                bac = ArrayUtils.add(bac, f);
            } else if (b[i] == true && b[i] == true) {
                bac = ArrayUtils.add(bac, t);
            } else {
                bac = ArrayUtils.add(bac, f);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("a =" + Arrays.toString(a) + "\n");
        System.out.println("b =" + Arrays.toString(b) + "\n");
        System.out.println("c =" + Arrays.toString(c) + "\n");
        System.out.println("b^c = "+Arrays.toString(bac) + "\n");
        
        //for A Or (B and C)
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (bac[i] != a[i]) {
                aobac = ArrayUtils.add(aobac, t);
            }else if (bac[i] == true && a[i] == true) {
                aobac = ArrayUtils.add(aobac, t);
            }else {
                aobac = ArrayUtils.add(aobac, f);
            }
            
        }
        System.out.print("aV(b^c) = "+Arrays.toString(aobac));
    }

}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: `else if (b[i] == true && b[i] == true)` should be `else if (b[i] == true && c[i] == true)`, or even better `else if (b[i] && c[i])`, or just drop the whole `if` sequence and just do `bac = ArrayUtils.add(bac, b[i] || c[i]);`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will close it in 10 min. @KenY-N

Comment: I must have typed it wrong but somehow it works.

Comment: I can't delete the post... @KenY-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to print something like this?

```
a      b      c      a | (b & c)
false  false  false  false
false  false  true   false
false  true   false  false
false  true   true   true
true   false  false  true
true   false  true   true
true   true   false  true
true   true   true   true
```

```java
System.out.println("a      b      c      a | (b & c)");
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 3); i++) {
    boolean a = (i & 0b100) != 0;
    boolean b = (i & 0b010) != 0;
    boolean c = (i & 0b001) != 0;
    boolean r = a | (b & c);
    System.out.printf("%-5s  %-5s  %-5s  %s%n", a, b, c, r);
}
```